# Crontab job not executing in django project

Tags: python, django, cron, pipenv

I am using crontab to execute certain function, however when i run the server the job is not processed. When i use the command crontab show , it shows me the job , bit again when i run the server its not executed. I followed this documentation https://pypi.org/project/django-crontab/ and watched YT tutorial as well but nothing worked.

crontab -l. shows this : '*/1 * * * * /Users/nourelgeziry/.local/share/virtualenvs/Equal_Distribution_maintainance-M-bcKwQz/bin/python /Users/nourelgeziry/Desktop/MyProjects/Equal Distribution maintainance/EDMS/manage.py crontab run bd84e5bec9ad4805b334e11fafec1b5c # django-cronjobs for EDMS' .

Also worth mentioning i am using pipenv for the virtual env.

Let me know if there is anything i can provide more . Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use Django crontabs as well before, but I never managed to get them working.

What I did instead was creating custom Django commands that could be executed using for example 'python3 manage.py send_emails' (if send_emails was the name of my custom command).

How to create custom Django commands is documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

So, here's what I did:

1 - Create a custom django command

2 - Create a sh file that cd into your Django project directory and runs python3 manage.py name_of_your_command

3 - Set up a cronjob to execute the sh file periodically

Comment: thank you for the help, i created my custom command and sh file and it works fine. When it comes to the cron job, how can i make the cron job execute only when the django server runs as my custom command queries and deletes objects from database.